# First tab not in focus on page load

Tags: javascript, html

In my webpage there is a tabs feature containing 3 tabs. On Page load I want the first tab and its related content in focus and styled as if the User has selected it.

The HTML "snippet" for the tabs is managed in a CMS > CKEditor WYSIWYG. I can add source code to this editor, including JS, but I am unable to edit the source code of the underlying page (it is what it is).

The JS tabs code is a call in the Head.

The code works as stand-alone page, i.e. onload the page renders with the first tab and it's content in focus. However, when rendered through the CMS it shows the three tabs, with none of the tabs (and content) in focus. The tabs do work when user interacts with the interface.

The html code:

```
<li class="tablinks" id="defaultOpen" onclick="switchView('economicSustainability'); myFunctionEconomic(); openTab(event, 'tab1')">One</li>
<li class="tablinks" onclick="switchView('customerFocus'); myFunctionCustomer(); openTab(event, 'tab2')">Two</li>
<li class="tablinks" onclick="switchView('customerFocus'); myFunctionSource(); openTab(event, 'tab3')">Three</li>
<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="economicDiv">Content here</div>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="customerDiv">Content here</div>
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="sourceDiv">Content here</div>
</div>
```

The JS code:

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

I would be grateful for any help that might be gleamed from the above. My thanks! Nick

(edit: I've just learned, I can have the JS tabs code updated if need be)

Comment: might want to wrap your defaultopen click inside a settimeout,0 to push it to the end of the stack, make sure it runs after render

Comment: thanks @tik27 I'm afraid I don;t understand what that means. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Can you, or anyone else :) suggest how I might achieve the result I'm looking for? I've tried adding the setTimeOut entry but it's not working for me. Thank you

Comment: Thx @tik27, It worked as you suggested. setTimeout was the go